# How to escape colon in php?

Tags: php, css

I want add new font to array with this format

```
font-family: yekan,open_sans;
```

how i can add this and escape colon. it must be like this:

```
'yekan,open_sans'=>'yekan+sans'
```

---

```
$my_fonts = array(
'Arial' => 'Arial',
'Times New Roman' => 'Times New Roman',
'DroidArabicKufi' => 'DroidArabicKufi',
'SourceSansSemiBold' => 'SourceSansSemiBold',
'sourceSans' => 'sourceSans'
);
```

Comment: there is no colon in your example

Comment: the question is really what is a valid array key which is the same as a variable "Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. "